# Kotlin JS and Lenses

Tags: kotlin, lenses, kotlin-js

I need lenses on nested data classes in Kotlin for the JavaScript target.

Since Arrow is not available for KotlinJS: Are there any libraries, examples, gists, available? Or has at least somebody an idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Doesn't Arrow-Optics just generate standard Kotlin code? Maybe you could just generate the lenses, and compile them to JS?

Comment: As far as I know, Arrow extends the companion object at compile time. Do I have no idea, how to (automatically) use this code in my JS-project.

Comment: Started to write a small lib/plugin for this: https://github.com/jwstegemann/fritz2-optics. Help appreciated... ;-)